# How to add a file upload field in Swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor, swagger-3.0

I'm trying to specify file input in swagger.

ImportUser:

```
  properties:
    user_type_id:
      description: ID of the related user type
      type: integer
      format: int32
      example: '1'
      nullable: false
    csv_file:
      description: CSV file
      type: **file**
    skip_first_row:
      description: Identify whether first row should be skipped
      type: string
      format: unique
      maxLength: 100
      minLength: 1
      example: '1'
      nullable: false
  type: object
```

File upload button is shownin editor, but I'm getting following error:

> Structural error at
>   components.schemas.ImportOperatorDevice.properties.csv_file.type
>   should be equal to one of the allowed values allowedValues: array,
>   boolean, integer, number, object, string

Comment: Do you use `swagger: '2.0'` or `openapi: 3.0.0`? How is the raw request supposed to look like - is it a POST request with `multipart/form-data` or something else?

Comment: It's openapi 3.0.0. And it's POST request with multipart/form-data.

Comment: Tried that already, but when I specify it like type:string format:binary, error message is gone but then upload button is missing.

Comment: Can you post your complete definition (with `type:string` + `format:binary`) and also add a screenshot of the missing upload button?

Comment: SOLVED :) It's OK with string + binary now, probably some browser caching thing. Thank you!